# Swift - Decode specific key using jsonDecoder

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I'm not sure how to word my question, but I'm trying to find how to decode not a whole json, but only a specific key without creating multiple models.

JSON example:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "From DC Comics comes the Suicide Squad, an antihero team of incarcerated supervillains who act as deniable assets for the United States government, undertaking high-risk black ops missions in exchange for commuted prison sentences.",
      "release_date": "2016-08-03",
      "genre_ids": [
        14,
        28,
        80
      ],
      "id": 297761,
      "original_title": "Suicide Squad",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Suicide Squad",
      "backdrop_path": "/ndlQ2Cuc3cjTL7lTynw6I4boP4S.jpg",
      "popularity": 48.261451,
      "vote_count": 1466,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.91
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I only need to get `results`.
Now I have 2 models:

```
struct Movies: Codable {
    let results: [MovieResult]?
}

struct MovieResult: Codable {
    let popularity: Double?
    let poster_path: String?
    let backdrop_path: String?
    let title: String?
    let vote_average: Double?
    let overview: String?
    let release_date: String?
}
```

And getting decoding:

```
        RESTful.request(path: path, method: "GET", parameters: parameters, headers: nil) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(.networkingError))
            case .success(let data):
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
                    let popularMovies = try jsonDecoder.decode(Movies.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(popularMovies))
                } catch (let error) {
                    completion(.failure(.errorDecoding))
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way(using jsonDecoder) to decode it to a single model, since I only need `results`?

Comment: This is impossible because you need to set codings keys for a needed key (results for example) and you need a container (model) for that. Ofc you can decode it to [String: AnyObject] dictionary and after that try to find the result key inside, but it is a terrible way. It is better to create wrapper like Movies. it is not a problem

Comment: @AlexanderNikolaychuk thanks, I felt like I was doing something wrong.

Comment: no it is all fine with your decode wrappers. It possible to avoid the nested wrappers (look for nestedContainer) but with first level container you can’t do that, it is all fine here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON must be decoded always from the root object.

But there is a very simple solution, declare the `Result` type

```
Result<MovieResult,Error>
```

and call `completion` on success

```
completion(.success(popularMovies.results))
```